# the characteristics function is surjective if and only if A is a proper subset of $\Omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\chi_a$ is surjective if and only if A is a proper subset of $\Omega$

where $\chi_a: \text{characteristics function} $

**My attempt:**
$(\implies)$ Let $\chi_a:\Omega\rightarrow\{0,1\}$

By hypothesis we know $\chi_a$ is surjective. This implies for each $y\in \{0,1\}$ exists $x\in \Omega$ such that $\chi_A(x)=y$.

here i'm stuck can someone help me?

Comment: I think you are confusing the definition of injective with surjective.

Comment: Hint: If the map is surjective, for every element $b\in \{0,1\}$, you can find $a \in \Omega$ such that $\chi_A(a) = b$. Thus, the idea is that both $0,1$ are mapped to by some element of $\Omega$. Use this to conclude ...

Comment: oh... true! sorry for the confusing that i will edit my question @rubikscube09

Comment: then exists $a\in \Omega$ such that $\chi (a)=y$ and $a\not \in A$? @rubikscube09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a set and $A \subseteq X$.

$\chi_A: X \to \{0,1\}$ is surjective iff $A \neq \emptyset$ and $A \neq X$.

$\Leftarrow$: Let $x \in A$ and $x' \in X$ and $x'\notin A$. Then $\chi_A(x) = 1$ (as $x \in A$) and $\chi_A(x')=0$ (as $x' \notin A$) and so $\chi_A$ assumes both values of the codomain.

$\Rightarrow$: As $\chi_A[X]=\{0,1\}$ there must be some $x \in A$ with $\chi_A(x)=0$ and some $x' \in X$ with $\chi_A(x')=1$. Then $x$ witnesses that $A \subsetneq X$ and $x'$ that $A \neq \emptyset$.